# What is the plural of tablix?

Tags: grammatical-number, terminology, technology

Don't know why the word *table* wasn't good enough for Microsoft, but SQL Server Reporting Services has a control called a *tablix*....

But how would I tell you that I have multiple tablix controls?

(I appear [not to be the only one](http://www.bidn.com/forums/microsoft-business-intelligence/reporting-services/835/multiple-tablix-controls-on-a-report) with this question)

Tablix does not appear in NGrams's English corpus.

A quick search on Google reveals no dictionaries that contain the word, but the search *"tablixes" SQL* returns 4,730 results, and the search *"tablices" SQL* returns 1,160 results.

Comment: Seeing that `matrix` (a parallel control to `tablix`) can be pluralized as *either* `matrixes` or `matrices`, I propose that `tablix` should follow the same rule.

Answer (score 1):

*Tablix* is a portmanteau of [*table* and *matrix*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934258%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) (and possibly *list* as well). The preferred plural, as noted in your post, appears to be *tablixes* rather than *tablices*. Considering its contrived etymology, this might be for the best.

Comment: New coinages and polysemes are tending to be given regular plurals - hence mouses for the computer variety.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've only really heard _mice_. IMO, the increase in the use of regular plurals is more due to AmE. Most new coinages (esp. technical) tend to have American origins.